# How to avoid pushing duplicate objects in state array in reactjs..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The below given state is in my class component. Need to avoid adding duplicate objects in an array my state is given below

```
this.state = {
      frequency: {
        time: [
                {time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},
                {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}
              ],
      },
    };
```

the requirement is sholud not add the object with same time and timezone value.
my push code is given below

```
 this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        frequency: {
          ...state.frequency,
          time: [...state.frequency.time, selecttime],
        },
        )}
     ))
```

the selecttime which carries the object which im going to push in the time array

```
const selecttime = {time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}
```

i should not adding same object again. how do i avoid pushing duplicate objects in state array

Comment: use `array.find` to check if same entry exists, its not a react question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to search the array to see if any duplicates exist. The following is *one* way to search an array.

```
const isDuplicate = (data, obj) =>
  data.some((el) =>
    Object.entries(obj).every(([key, value]) => value === el[key])
  );
```

The outer loop is searching for *some* element that matches *every* object property using the inner loop to the reference object value. If an element is found with all properties equal to the reference object, return true, false otherwise.

```js
const data = [
  {
    time: "20:15",
    timezone: "IST"
  },
  {
    time: "01:30",
    timezone: "UST"
  }
];

const isDuplicate = (data, obj) =>
  data.some((el) =>
    Object.entries(obj).every(([key, value]) => value === el[key])
  );

console.log(
  isDuplicate(data, {
    time: "20:15",
    timezone: "IST"
  })
); // true
console.log(
  isDuplicate(data, {
    time: "21:15",
    timezone: "IST"
  })
); // false
```

Only update state if not a duplicate

```
if (!isDuplicate(state.frequency.time, selecttime)) {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    frequency: {
      ...state.frequency,
      time: [...state.frequency.time, selecttime],
    },
    )}
  ));
}
```