# How to prevent adding duplicate objects into array in state in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am fetching from an API that returns data in the form of an array. Lets say I have an array of 5 objects in this array which are exactly the same.  I want to prevent duplicates by checking if duplicate exists before adding to my `restaurants` State. Below are snippets of my code:

```
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([])
```

```
const checkForDuplicateBusiness = (businessArray)=>{
    businessArray.forEach(singleBusiness=>{
      if(!restaurants.some(restaurant=> restaurant.id === singleBusiness.id)){
        setRestaurants(restaurants=>[...restaurants, singleBusiness])
        console.log(restaurants) //returns []
      }
    })
  }
```

The problem is that when I am checking with this line
`if(!restaurants.some(restaurant=> restaurant.id === singleBusiness.id))`
the `restaurants` state is always empty. I understand that setState is async so the state is not updated by the time im checking it for the next iteration in the forEach loop. Im not sure what to do.

When I console log the restaurants via useEffect like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(restaurants)
},[restaurants])
```

it will show 5 identical objects.

```
[
   0: {id: 'sDlYSTdgZCx0-3cRetKn8A'}
   1: {id: 'sDlYSTdgZCx0-3cRetKn8A'}
   2: {id: 'sDlYSTdgZCx0-3cRetKn8A'}
   3: {id: 'sDlYSTdgZCx0-3cRetKn8A'}
   4: {id: 'sDlYSTdgZCx0-3cRetKn8A'}
]
```

I am confused on this behavior because if i have exactly 5 copies of the object, that means my `setRestaurants(restaurants=>[...restaurants, singleBusiness])` was working properly indicative from the **spread operator**. but my check **if statement** isnt?

The other solution I've thought of is to store my fetched data in a temporary array and perform the "preventDuplicate" logic in there, and then set it to my `restaurants.` But I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method. Is there a better way or the "React" way for this?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1. create a new array by concatenating the current state array and the loaded array 2. remove all dupes from the array using any method (google will help) 3. call setState *once* passing the final array

Comment: yes sorry typo. ive updated question

Comment: If the idea is to add those entries from `businessArray` into `restaurants` as long as the `id` does not already exists, one single `setRestaurants` (as shown in my previous comment, above) may be sufficient.

Comment: @jsN00b That won't work because `prev` is an array of objects, not ids.

Comment: Seems complicated problem due to miss understanding React capabilities. React simply wrapper for html. Which makes React View side of problem. Bussiness logic where we store and manuplate it different issue. So that redux invented.  You may solve this problem but please consider to use redux for data manuplation for your future project. It will ease you work.

Comment: @jsN00b Ive tried your suggestion with the updated .map but I get an Array of 6 empty arrays. platonics answer actually resolves my issue. Thank you !!

Comment: @OsmanCorluk i appreciate the feedback, I heard of redux, but have no idea what that is. Thank you for the suggestion1

Comment: Is this what you tried? ---> `const checkForDuplicateBusiness = (businessArray) => setRestaurants(prev => [...prev, businessArray.filter(bu => prev.map(({ id }) => id).includes(bu.id))]);`. This is what I suggest. No need of `.forEach`, etc. Personally, I will not make a `setState` call within a loop - it's unnecessary to call that once per iteration. I'd rather gather all of the data outside the loop & make just the one call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid pushing duplicate objects in state array in reactjs..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347809/how-to-avoid-pushing-duplicate-objects-in-state-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: Here's a three line solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-bash-nosq5y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @jsN00b ive tried your first suggestion and the recent suggestion but I get still get an array with empty arrays. how come you prefer to `setState` just once, is the efficiency better with your suggested approach

Comment: @pilchard yes, my code is actually based on that post.... but ive modified it because my `state` is an array, instead of an object

Comment: @ChrisG wow thank you so much I  ran it through a huge data fetch and it works. I am new to SO-- is it possible to use this as the answer to my question somehow?? i appreciate your help!

Comment: No, but removing duplicates from an array is a solved problem so this is a dupe anyway. You're welcome though :)

Comment: @benwl - the condition needed to be `!prev.map()`. It checks for dupes on existing `restaurants` and not on the `businessArray`. The one by ChrisG checks dupes overall.

Comment: @ChrisG so I realize I ran into the same issue if I were to perform multiple fetch requests repeatedly, which forces me to put the `setState` inside a `for` loop. which brought me back to my original questions. the code from your codesandbox link (changed) was `const removeDuplicates = (businessArray) => {
      const dataMap = new Map();
      restaurants.concat(businessArray).forEach((res) => dataMap.set(res.id, res));
      setRestaurants(Array.from(dataMap.values()));
    };` im not sure how to go about the for loop as I depend on the current State. i really appreciate any help

Comment: When you say multiple requests repeatedly, can you be a bit more specific? Also, I don't think this forces you to use a for loop; you could load everything first, then do the usual duplicate elimination.

Comment: @ChrisG My use case is i have many coordinates in fetch i need to fetch "restaurants" nearby. I could load everything first with promise.all but I would preferably like the components to render as my `restaurants` state updates so my application doesnt "load" for too long without anything being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The `setStateSetter` function gives you the updated state. Use it higher:

```
function uniqueById(items) {
  const set = new Set();
  return items.filter((item) => {
    const isDuplicate = set.has(item.id);
    set.add(item.id);
    return !isDuplicate;
  });
}

const updateRestaurantsUnique = (newItems) => {
  setRestaurants((restaurants) => {
    return uniqueById([...restaurants, ...newItems]);
  });
};
```